# Create setup for project in C# with EF

Tags: c#, deployment, installation

I have a project consisting out of two solutions which use Entity Framework.
How can I create a setup with EF to easy install on other computer as single application?

Comment: can you elaborate more in details?

Comment: What you mean `two solutions with Entity Frameworks`?

Comment: What does EF have to do with creating an installer? Is it a desktop application, a web site, what?

Comment: Doesn't matter what the application involves generally speaking. you can create installers and the like and deploy the application - that is what installers do.

Comment: Installers are very rarely used for deploying web applications, or applications that need to install web services and databases. The type of applications matters a lot.

Comment: It is a desktop application. Two solutions - one with app and second with EF database and handling for this. I mean - create setup, install on computer, create database with dynamic connection string